# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename error when dropping foreign key in Doctrine Migration

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-migrations

I am seeing the error below when I run the following query inside a Doctrine migration:

`ALTER TABLE crmpicco_course_version DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_C060B146DE13F470`

```
Migration 20151209153121 failed during Execution. 
Error An exception occurred while executing 
'ALTER TABLE crmpicco_course_version DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_C060B146DE13F470':

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 
1025 Error on rename of './crmpicco_dev/crmpicco_course_version' 
to './crmpicco_dev/#sql2-77c-b0a' (errno: 152)
```

This is the table I am trying to change:

```
CREATE TABLE `crmpicco_course_version` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `course_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_by_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_C060B146896DBBDE` (`updated_by_id`),
  KEY `IDX_C060B146DE13F470` (`course_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_C060B146896DBBDE` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by_id`) REFERENCES `crmpicco_user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_C060B146DE13F470` FOREIGN KEY (`course_id`) REFERENCES `crmpicco_course` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

What is preventing me from dropping this foreign key successfully?

When I run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` I get the following:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
151209 16:25:42 Error IN dropping of a FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT of TABLE "crmpicco_dev"."crmpicco_course_version",
IN SQL command
ALTER TABLE crmpicco_course_version DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_C060B146DE13F470
Cannot find a CONSTRAINT WITH the given id "FK_C060B146DE13F470".
```

Comment: What does `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` show after you run the query?

Comment: @tftd I have updated the question with the output. The `CONSTRAINT` is removed before the `FOREIGN KEY` is, however this is my understanding on how Doctrine migrations work. This is confirmed by stof here https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/issues/83#issuecomment-7261301

Comment: Interesting... I have a feeling this might be a bug. Look at this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cc3a/1) which proves the sql code works fine. Have you tried to update the doctrine dependency or mysql? While searching for the `errorno:152` I noticed a couple of topics on the official form of mysql. There are a few here on SO as well.

Comment: @tftd Yes, i've had an extensive look around into this. The advice on the MySQL site (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-error-codes.html) is `To avoid getting this error while trying to drop a foreign key, use the constraint name rather than the column name of the foreign key.` (which I am doing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After endless dropping and recreating of my local database I found that this was caused by Doctrine creating the same `ALTER` statement more than once **and also** in the wrong order.

I had to change the statements around manually to make sure I migrated data from my old table to my new table before creating the new foreign key constraint on the new table. Without this change I was getting the error above and others.

Comment: Cheers! Had the same problem, glad to know it wasn't me going crazy

Comment: To prevent large jumps in the auto increment id, I was using `alter` to reset the auto_increment value after a loop of "on duplicate key update" statements. I didn't even have any foreign keys on the table, or referencing the table!